# Error undefined is not a function for .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I keep getting `undefined is not a function` error and I don't know why, can anyone help shed some light.

here is the whole bit of code

```
 (function(){

                var sliders = $('section.content-25').hide();
                var slidersOrder = sliders.each(function(i){
                                                var i = i - 1;
                                                $(this).addClass("slider"+(i+1));
                                            });

                $(".project-wrapper").on('click', function(){

                    var btnOrder = $(this).index();
                    var sliderClass = ("slider"+btnOrder);

                     if (sliders.hasClass("slider"+btnOrder)) {

                            sliderClass.show();

                     }; 
                    event.preventDefault();

                 });//end of .on('click') function

            })();// end self envoking functions
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle? in wich line did you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT2:  jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/LpuLE/4

EDIT: Tried making sense from your code. Here is a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/LpuLE/3/

You had a couple problems with your code. I fixed most of them. You only need to make sure that this part : `var sliderClass = ("slider"+btnOrder);` is what you actually meant to do. To me it looks wrong. Looks as if you're trying to access an element and that it should look like: `var sliderClass = $("#slider "+btnOrder);` or something like that.

```
$('#slider1').hide();
$(".project-wrapper").on('click', function(){
                    var btnOrder = $(this).index();
                    alert(btnOrder);
                    var sliderClass = $("#slider"+btnOrder);

                     if (sliderClass.hasClass("slider"+btnOrder)) {

                            sliderClass.show();

                     }
 });
```

Comment: well what i was trying to do with the var slidersOrder is incrementally add classes like "slider1" then on the next div have it be "slider2" and so on.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. My edited example correct? What is "sliders" to you?

Comment: Ook well here is what im trying to do: i have 4 buttons and 4 larger divs that i defined as sliders. Whenever i click a certain button i want to show the div that corresponds to that button. So how i was trying to do this is by indexing each button and giving a class to the slides that would correspond with the buttons

Comment: You should have probably mentioned that at the beginning. I'll update my jsfiddle for you. Give me a couple minutes.

Comment: im making a jsfiddle dont worry about it

Comment: No problem. Make sure to choose my reponse as an answer. :D and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an undefined variable in your code -

```
if (sliders.hasClass("slider"+btnOrder)) {
```

**sliders** is not defined in the function anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your js has lots of problem I think:

where `sliders` variable is defined??

```
var sliderClass // I think you are trying to create jQuery DOM object here which is not correct
```

It should be something like this

```
var sliderClass = $(".slider"+btnOrder);
```